# Node JS: res.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm in the midst of making my first simple counter strike api bot with nodeJS, however I'm running into some problems with the res.send function. When I use it it throws the following error: "res.send is not a function". I've tried moving the res.send outside of the request, however that only updates my data after I refresh the page. Any help would be appreciated as I've been stuck on this problem for a while now.

My code :

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
var request = require("request")

/*const getSkinfo = require('./wyrskin')*/
const app = express()
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public')
var skins_str = "empty"
app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath))
/*var string_skin = (JSON.stringify(getSkinfo))*/
app.get('/skin', (req, res) => {

    request('https://api.steamapis.com/market/items/730?api_key=xyz', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        var skins = []
        var score = 0
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < body.data.length; i++) {
            var name = body.data[i].market_name
            var price = body.data[i].prices
            var img_url = body.data[i].image
            if (name.includes('Factory New') && !name.includes('StatTrak')) {
                skins.push(name + "," + price.avg + "^" + img_url)

            }
        }
        var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1215);
        var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1215);
        var out1 = "A : " + skins[num1]
        var out2 = "B : " + skins[num2]

        var mySubString1 = out1.substring(
            out1.lastIndexOf(",") + 1,
            out1.lastIndexOf("^")
        );
        var price1 = parseFloat(mySubString1)

        var mySubString2 = out2.substring(
            out2.lastIndexOf(",") + 1,
            out2.lastIndexOf("^")
        );
        var price2 = parseFloat(mySubString2)

        skins_str = (out1 + " ~ " + out2)
        console.log(skins_str)
        res.send({ skins: skins_str })

    })

})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port 3000.')



})
```

Thank you !

Comment: You have two `res` variables in your code. You are clobbering the first on in the route callback with the second one in the request callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really how I would proxy a request from a node server.  Checkout the node-fetch npm package.  Promises really clean up the code.

But the error in your code is that you have another res variable in the scope of this function.  If you rename it to response it should work?

Also use `res.json()` instead if you are just sending an object in your response.

Hope this helps!

```js
app.get('/skin', (req, res) => {

    request('https://api.steamapis.com/market/items/730?api_key=xyz', { json: true }, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        var skins = []
        var score = 0
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < body.data.length; i++) {
            var name = body.data[i].market_name
            var price = body.data[i].prices
            var img_url = body.data[i].image
            if (name.includes('Factory New') && !name.includes('StatTrak')) {
                skins.push(name + "," + price.avg + "^" + img_url)

            }
        }
        var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1215);
        var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1215);
        var out1 = "A : " + skins[num1]
        var out2 = "B : " + skins[num2]

        var mySubString1 = out1.substring(
            out1.lastIndexOf(",") + 1,
            out1.lastIndexOf("^")
        );
        var price1 = parseFloat(mySubString1)

        var mySubString2 = out2.substring(
            out2.lastIndexOf(",") + 1,
            out2.lastIndexOf("^")
        );
        var price2 = parseFloat(mySubString2)

        skins_str = (out1 + " ~ " + out2)
        console.log(skins_str)
        res.json({ skins: skins_str })

    })

})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port 3000.')



})
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, I'm going to look into refactoring once it's finished. But yeah that worked!